# How to get Images from Internet and past it in a ListView?

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I'm doing my BlogApp. It gets all data from the Internet. I added three TextViews, but I have problem with getting images from JSON. I've tryed different ways but I still don't understand how exactly do this. Here is a part of my code:

```
 private void handleBlogResponse() {
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    if (mBlogData==null){
        updateDisplayForError();

    }else {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonPosts = mBlogData.getJSONArray("posts");
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> blogPosts = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            for (int i=0; i<jsonPosts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject posts = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = posts.getString(KEY_TITLE); //"title"
                title = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();
                String author = posts.getString(KEY_AUTHOR); //"author"
                author = Html.fromHtml(author).toString();
                String time = posts.getString((KEY_TIME));  //"time"
                time = Html.fromHtml(time).toString();
                String icon = posts.getString(KEY_ICON);  //"icon" (icons url)
                icon = Html.fromHtml(icon).toString();
```

I stoped here, and don't know what to do next! Probably I should add an Adapter for my Images to convert it?

```
                HashMap<String, String> blogPost = new HashMap<String, String>();
                blogPost.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
                blogPost.put(KEY_AUTHOR, author);
                blogPost.put(KEY_TIME, time);

                blogPosts.add(blogPost);
            }

            String[] keys = {KEY_TITLE, KEY_AUTHOR, KEY_TIME};
            int[] ids = {R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3};
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, blogPosts, R.layout.row_layout,
                    keys, ids);
            setListAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for waching this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volley Library makes this work quite easy and handles all other related tasks itself. You can use ImageLoader or NetworkImageView.
Follow the link for how to acheive it: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html

Comment: Thank's It helps me I almost done it, but I faced with encoding problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30472366/fail-with-utf-8-encoding-in-volley-requests

Comment: @Nikolai I have done UTF encoding and it works fine for me. If you want more help please share the exact code. If your problem is solved; please mark it as answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all download image from url then set it into your imageView.

```
public class LoadImageFromURL extends AsyncTask{  
@Override  
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {  

try {
URL url = new URL("image-url");  
InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();  
Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);  
return bitMap;  

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {

e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;

}
@Override  
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onPostExecute(result);
yourImageview.setImageBitmap(result);
}

}
```

I Hope it will help you..!

Comment: Thanks, for your attention, but could it possible to download all images without writing url for each image? Using key word "post"? As I understood, each time when I add post I should add new image url to this code?