# download a file which is coming from a rest webservice in Android app

Tags: android, web-services, asynchttpclient

How to receive the file coming from web service in Android?

**Web Service code :**

```
private static final String FILE_PATH = "D:\\visitorHistory.csv";

@GET
@Path("/exportCsv")
@Produces("application/octet-stream")
public Response downloadFile() {
  File file = new File(FILE_PATH);
  ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
  response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=visitorHistory.csv");
  return response.build();
}
```

**Android code:**

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.getHttpClient().getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, true);
client.get(restServiceConstants.EXPORTCSV , null, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

  @Override
  public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {

    super.onSuccess(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "on sucess"+arg2.length, 100).show();
    for (int i = 0; i < arg2.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(arg2[i]);              
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "on sucess"+arg1[0], 100).show();
    }

  }
  @Override
  public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2, Throwable arg3){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onFailure(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
  }
});
```

Comment: Use volley library to handle all your such tasks.The link below can be helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30453679/how-to-get-images-from-internet-and-past-it-in-a-listview/30455179#30455179

Comment: Can you share the log

Comment: I don't know how to receive it in AsyncHttpClient could you suggets

Comment: Did  you get any call back in onSuccess or in onFailure?

Comment: when click on the component it hitting the server and returning to the onsuccess

Comment: Can you convert the byte array to string and print in log and check

Comment: thank you I'm getting the file data in byte array but when I invoke the url in android browser file is downloading directly. cant we download the file like android browser in my app